# Get array of objects from array (of strings e.g.)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get array of objects from array of strings.
For examaple:

```
var arr = ["1005", "1005", "1005", "1006", "1006", "1006", "1007", "1007"];



   var result = arr.reduce((iss, index) => {
  iss[index] = (iss[index] || 0) + 1;
    return iss 
}, {});
```

and the result would be

```
{1005: 3, 1006: 3, 1007: 2}
```

So is there a way to get next output:

```
[{"1005":3},{"1006":3},{"1007":2}]
```

Comment: Why? There is no advantage of that structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want that:

```
 result = Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! All of you help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `result` by iterating its keys

```
result = Object.keys ( result ).map( s => ({ [s] : result[s] }) );
```